# R: find first and last date in time data

Tags: r

I have a data frame containing dates, and i need to find the first and last date excluding the year.
There is a part of my dates:

```
2003-09-27
2004-09-17
2005-09-23
2006-09-21
2007-09-20
2008-09-26
2009-10-11
2010-09-28
2011-09-01
```

To be sure to translate what i want in english i'll put this in question form.

That would answer this question like this:
-Of all that survey, which year did your start the counts the earlier ?
- It was the 09-17 in 2004.

How could I find this date ?

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT**
I try to find automatically which date is the earlier of all my survey. These dates are count days, and i need to find which year the count session started the most early. I'm not searching for the widest range. I think I need to get rid of the year to find this. It seems I cant cut the year apart and keep the date format, because when i print the "Month-Day" part, it add automatically 2013.

The second part of my question is: when this date has been found, how can i call the whole date (with year) as it is in my entry data frame?

I hope its clearer now!

Comment: The question is not clear. what is the expected result? Do you want the rage for each year ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the supplied data, this should identify the 1st of September in 2011 as being the earliest date (as opposed to the 17th of September in 2004).

```
dates <- c("2003-09-27", "2004-09-17", "2005-09-23", "2006-09-21", 
           "2007-09-20", "2008-09-26", "2009-10-11", "2010-09-28", 
           "2011-09-01")

dates[order(format(as.Date(dates),"%m%d"))[1]]
#[1] "2011-09-01"
# it works!
```

Comment: Yes! That is exactly what i wanted! Thanks! For posterity, i found the latest date by replacing [1] by [length(dates)]

Comment: Thanks thelatemail. I found that using the format string "%Y%m%d" is necessary where dates are formatted without padding zeros. i.e. 2011-5-1.

Answer (score 4):

Just use `range`, no need to convert to date:

```
dates <- c("2003-09-15", "2002-04-04", "2002-11-17", "2005-09-23", 
           "2013-03-03", "2005-08-04", "2011-05-05", "2013-08-08", "2013-01-04")

# Find which years we have
years <- strftime(dates, "%Y")

res <- sapply(unique(years), function(y){
      # Find which days are in the specific year we're looking at
      idx <- which(years==y); 
      # Return the range
      return(range(dates[idx]));
      })

> res
     2003         2002         2005         2013         2011        
[1,] "2003-09-15" "2002-04-04" "2005-08-04" "2013-01-04" "2011-05-05"
[2,] "2003-09-15" "2002-11-17" "2005-09-23" "2013-08-08" "2011-05-05"
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, your answer actually helped me to find a solution to another problem (mean differences in days for all the survey), but did not answer my first question. I have trouble explaining what i really want so i edited my question.

Answer (score -1):

```
dates <- structure(c(12322, 12678, 13049, 13412, 13776, 14148, 14528, 
                 14880, 15218), class = "Date")

md <- (as.numeric(format(dates, "%m%d")))
dates[c(which.min(md), which.max(md))]
```